# Apache server not available externally

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, firewall, port-forwarding

I am building a server with Apache on my RPi. Locally, it works great! Externally, not so well. I got a friend to put in the External IP, but his iPhone told him: "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding". The ports and firewall on my router are configured, but it still does not work. So I made sure my Raspberry Pi's firewall allowed the port. I even changed the external port just in case my ISP was blocking it but when I tried to load it on my computer, my browser told me that it can't connect to the server. If my ISP is blocking my server, can I get around it? And if it's my router blocking it, how can I get around that? (I have a Netgear R5900P). I've been doing a lot of searching and I have not found the answer yet. A simple and clear answer would be very appreciated.

Here's what my router port forwarding configuration:

[image: My router port forwarding configuration picture]

This was logged in Apache's "error log":

```
[Sun Dec 10 14:34:34.071343 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 574]AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 10 14:35:58.725821 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 608] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 14:35:58.727766 2017] [core:notice] [pid 608] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Do your router and your ISP allow loop-back? If so, enter `NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:1207` where `NNN...` are your external IP address. Is this what your friend typed into Safari? If not, what did he type? If you can't do loop-back and you use 80 as both the external and internal port number, you should be able to test your site through a proxy. If all else fails, use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.com/) to log traffic to and from the server.

Comment: @AFH I'm not sure what loop-back is. I'm not sure on a lot of stuff lol all this stuff (servers, ports, etc) is all new to me. Yes, my friend typed the external IP and port number in his browser (ex: http://204.1.xxx.xxx:1207).

Comment: Loop-back in this case means allowing a request directed at your router's external address from within the same router's intranet.

Comment: I don't know if our router has that or not. It's a Netgear. I'll take a look.

Comment: @AFH Yes, my router has loop back.

Comment: Then you can do all your testing from the same machine as you used for internal tests, but using the external address.

Comment: @AFH Oh, I get it, I didn't know that was loopback. So I've been doing a little bit of that (testing the external address within the same network with loopback) but it still does not work.

Comment: Then you'll need to monitor network traffic to and from the web server (192.168.1.17). Compare a successful internal connection with an unsuccessful external one. If no traffic gets through the external interface, you'll need to compare traffic to and from the client PC.

Comment: @AFH I'm not sure how to do that. I'm new to this. Do I use WireShark that you told me earlier?

Comment: Do you see log entries at your server when you connect to your apache from external ip?
You can find this in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Yes, I see lots of them.

Comment: Yes, though there are some friendlier traffic monitors, but these don't always give the same level of detail. You should also check the Apache logs to see if a connection was attempted. And double-check your firewall settings to make sure that both external and internal port 80 connections are allowed. I think we have reached the point now where you need to do some serious investigation of what's needed to monitor and interpret TCP traffic: there's a limit to what can be achieved by question and answer. It's late here and I have to stop, so don't expect any more immediate responses tonight.

Comment: @AFH Thanks for your help. I will be doing more research.

Comment: Can you post a few lines here, so we can localize the error?

Comment: Sure, here's a few:

Comment: [Sun Dec 10 14:34:34.071343 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 574] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 10 14:35:58.725821 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 608] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 14:35:58.727766 2017] [core:notice] [pid 608] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Ok, these are no configuration errors shown in the logs. So you only can test it from the client side. An easier way to get information about the connection is to use the developer tools in your browser. For example in Firefox you can analyse the connection by Ctrl+Shift+E and reloading the page. There you can see what requests the browser sends to the server and the response you get back.

Comment: Would I be able to do that on my computer even if I'm on the same network?

Comment: Yes, if you use the external ip you can do this.

Comment: I can't seem to do it. The commands might be a little different in Mac. What's the tool called? Also, when I put in the external IP, it asks for the username and password for "DSL Router".

Comment: If you use Safari yu have the developer tools: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-safari-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac I'm not shure about Safari, but you should have the Timeline Recording. Maybe this can help you, but please empty caches first.

Comment: Safari does have the Timeline Recording. So...I recorded it, what am I looking for?

Comment: @JakeGould Apache called it the error log, so I just call it that too. You say it a router issue? Any suggestions how to fix it? I'm at my ropes end.

Comment: Some ISPs block port 80. Maybe try an alternate port? Also worth checking if you have a proper public IP or your ISP uses CGN

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I changed the incoming port to 1207 but the router forwards it to port 80 where my server is listening. Would that keep the ISP from blocking it?

Comment: Assuming it's even open. Lots of isps just stick you behind a Nat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that my ISP is blocking it (although it could be the router) and I'm not sure there's not much I can about that. But I did find a detour. I dropped the idea of using port forwarding and IP addresses and all that, instead, I'm using a service called [Dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com/devices/) which accomplishes the same thing that I was aiming for initially but simplifies it. All I have to do is install some software from Dataplicity and enable the Wormhole feature. It works alongside Apache or other web server software. So far it has worked!